# My list is loading again when I am Pressing Back Button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-json

I am also getting ArrayListIndexOutofBound when I am pressing list item when the orientation is changed.As far my knowledge of android I have written Parcelable code correctly.But I think my issues are with the recycler view setup.I am confused with two declaration of my adapter.Help me

**MainActivity.class**

```
 package com.reader.ashishyadav271.hackernewsmaterial;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyCustomAdapter.ClickListener {

    private static final String STATE_LIST = "state_list";
    Map<Integer, String> articleURLs = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, String> articleTitles = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, String> articleDates =new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, String> articleAuthors =new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> articleIds=new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase articlesDB;

    ArrayList<Information> data=new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> titles=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> urls=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> authors=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> dateAndTimes=new ArrayList<>();
    MyCustomAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    AVLoadingIndicatorView av;
    List<DownloadTask> tasks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        av= (AVLoadingIndicatorView) findViewById(R.id.avloadingIndicatorView);
        av.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(
                getApplicationContext()
        ));



        articlesDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Articles", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        articlesDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                " articleId INTEGER," +
                " url VARCHAR," +
                " title VARCHAR," +
                " author VARCHAR," +
                " date VARCHAR)");

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {

            data=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_LIST);
            adapter=new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),data);
            adapter.setClickListener(this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }else{
            if (isOnline()) {

                requestData("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");
            } else {
                updateDisplay();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        //adapter=new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getData());
        //adapter.setClickListener(this);
        //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    protected boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void requestData(String uri) {
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
        i.putExtra("articleUrl", urls.get(position));
        startActivity(i);

    }

    protected void updateDisplay() {
        adapter=new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getData());
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putParcelableArrayList(STATE_LIST, data);

    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                av.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            tasks.add(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

            try {

                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();

                }

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                articlesDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM article");

                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

                    String articleId = jsonArray.getString(i);

                    url = new URL("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + articleId + ".json?print=pretty");

                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                    data = reader.read();

                    String articleInfo = "";

                    while (data != -1 ) {

                        char current = (char) data;

                        articleInfo += current;

                        data = reader.read();

                    }

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(articleInfo);

                    String articleTitle = jsonObject.getString("title");

                    String articleURL = jsonObject.getString("url");

                    String articleDate=jsonObject.getString("time");

                    String articleAuthor=jsonObject.getString("by");


                    long unixSeconds = Long.valueOf(articleDate);
                    Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); // *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // the format of your date
                    String formattedarticleDate = sdf.format(date);

                    articleIds.add(Integer.valueOf(articleId));
                    articleTitles.put(Integer.valueOf(articleId), articleTitle);
                    articleURLs.put(Integer.valueOf(articleId), articleURL);
                    articleDates.put(Integer.valueOf(articleId), formattedarticleDate);
                    articleAuthors.put(Integer.valueOf(articleId), articleAuthor);

                    String sql = "INSERT INTO article (articleId, url, title, author, date) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ?, ?)";


                    SQLiteStatement statement = articlesDB.compileStatement(sql);

                    statement.bindString(1, articleId);
                    statement.bindString(2, articleURL);
                    statement.bindString(3, articleTitle);
                    statement.bindString(4, articleAuthor);
                    statement.bindString(5, formattedarticleDate);

                    statement.execute();



                }


            }catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            tasks.remove(this);
            if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                av.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            updateDisplay();
        }
    }

    private List<Information> getData() {
        /*List<Information> data=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            titles.add(i,"Wikileaks Asssange wins UN ruling on arbitrary detention");
            url.add(i,"https://www.google.co.in/search?q=best+custom+list+row");
            date.add(i,"3 hrs");
            author.add(i,"aburan28");
        }
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            Information current=new Information();
            current.title=titles.get(i);
            current.url=url.get(i);
            current.author=author.get(i);
            current.date=date.get(i);
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;*/

        Cursor c = articlesDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM article", null);

        try {
            int urlIndex = c.getColumnIndex("url");
            int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("title");
            int authorIndex = c.getColumnIndex("author");
            int dateIndex = c.getColumnIndex("date");

            c.moveToFirst();

            titles.clear();
            //urls.clear();
            authors.clear();
            dateAndTimes.clear();


            int i=0;
            while (c != null) {
                titles.add(c.getString(titleIndex));
                urls.add(c.getString(urlIndex));
                authors.add(c.getString(authorIndex));
                dateAndTimes.add(c.getString(dateIndex));
                Information current=new Information();
                current.title=titles.get(i);
                current.url=urls.get(i);
                current.author=authors.get(i);
                current.date = dateAndTimes.get(i);
                data.add(current);
                i++;
                c.moveToNext();

            }


        }catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }finally {
            c.close();
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),About.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Information.class**

```
package com.reader.ashishyadav271.hackernewsmaterial;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Information implements Parcelable {
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public String date;
    public String url;

    public Information(){

    }

    protected Information(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
        author = in.readString();
        date = in.readString();
        url = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Information> CREATOR = new Creator<Information>() {
        @Override
        public Information createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Information(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Information[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Information[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(author);
        dest.writeString(date);
        dest.writeString(url);
    }
}
```

Log Cat Error

```
02-06 14:52:58.106 8369-8369/com.reader.ashishyadav271.hackernewsmaterial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.reader.ashishyadav271.hackernewsmaterial, PID: 8369
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at com.reader.ashishyadav271.hackernewsmaterial.MainActivity.itemClicked(MainActivity.java:137)
    at com.reader.ashishyadav271.hackernewsmaterial.MyCustomAdapter$MyViewHolder.onClick(MyCustomAdapter.java:77)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4471)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18778)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: wich list is throwing the error, please post the logcat!

Comment: You are not using the same arraylist/data that you used in Adapter and that is why the position at which the item is clicked is null in the urls data

Comment: and what about my data when I am pressing the back button it is again loading..

Comment: sir I have the same ArrayList<Information> data that is defined globally which is used to set

Comment: It didnt worked and nobody helped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get it after years.I would have simply used.
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP - If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.